# How to automate the population of taxonomy terms in drupal

Tags: drupal, migrate

I'm using the migrate module to import loads of content into my new drupal 7 site.  In doing this, i need to first of all autonomatically create the taxonomy terms so that i can map them to the data i want to put in them.

I've tried using features to automate the creation of a taxonomy and it didn't work.  I'd like to know how people go about this process - what's the best practice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the [Drush module](http://drupal.org/project/drush) which enables you to script things.